# Using class variables in methods of the same class in Python

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python at home using the Python for Dummies all in one book. I'm on the chapter about classes and in particular the section on class variables. So far, the code has been running fine, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work the way I expect.

My code is this:

```
class Crew_Member:
    """A class for creating an individual record"""
    is_human = True

    def __init__(self, full_name, username, rank="crewmember"):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.username = username
        self.rank = rank
        self.join_date = dt.date.today()

    def file_age(self):
        return f"{self.full_name}'s file was created on {self.join_date:%d/%m/%y}"

    def promote(self, rank):
        self.rank = rank

    def not_human(self):
        if Crew_Member.is_human:
            self.rank = "Mech/Scutter"
```

So my understanding is that `is_human` is the class variable. The method I'm trying to use it in is `not_human`. The idea is that each object would be the personel record for a crew member. If that crew member is not human, they automatically get the rank of "Mech/Scutter".

The way I imagined it working is after the object has been called, you change that instance's value of `is_human` to false, run the method `not_human`, and that would change their rank accordingly. The first time I tried and got the correct rank, the class variable hadn't changed:

[image: First try]

My code (as written above) works fine, but this is what I have to enter to get it to work:

[image: Final code]

So this is my problem: The for (edit: if) loop in the `not_human` method says "If *class variable* is true, then change rank". But the class variable has been changed to false (as illustrated by the first print line) so why does it work?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. Post a [mre] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `BobScutt.is_human = False` is _shadowing_ the class attribute with an instance attribute of the same name. `Crew_Member.is_human` remains the same, only `self.is_human` would change.

Comment: Leaving aside that it makes no sense for `is_human` to be a class variable, your `not_human` function says "If the crew member is human, make them a scutter" which can't really have been what you meant, presumably...?

Comment: "The for loop in the `not_human` method says..." - There is no for loop in that method. You mean the if statement.

Comment: Sorry about the pictures, didn't know that was a no-no @khelwood, and the reason I made it a class variable was that I couldn't think what else to make a class variable.
@ Antimon Changed, thank you.
@ jonrsharpe that makes sense, thanks, guess that's the problem of learning from a book alone.
Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the class variable has been changed to false...

No, the line `BobScutt.is_human = False` turns it into an *instance* variable. The class variable remains untouched. If you want to change it, you have to manipulate the `Crew_Member` class directly, not one of its instances.

Observe:

```py
class TestClass:
    test_attr = True
    
foo = TestClass()
foo.test_attr = False

print("Test attribute in foo:", foo.test_attr)
print("Test attribute in TestClass:", TestClass.test_attr)
```

Output:

```
Test attribute in foo: False
Test attribute in TestClass: True
```

Comment: Thank you Antimon, that makes sense. The book doesn't go into that much detail, so that doesn't help, but it's only a means to an end.